# Django: How to filter and display posts from categories on a page

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and have build a simple application that includes posts. I want to display posts that are associated with certain categories on one page. I did quite a bit of research online but can't seem to make it work. I think the problem is in my views.py

I guess there's something wrong with the get_queryset function in CategoryListView.

```
'''
models.py 
'''
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category', 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-category', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})




'''
views.py
'''
from django.views.generic import ListView    
from .models import Post, Category



class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts/post_category.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category,   id=self.kwargs.get('category__name'))
        return Posts.objects.filter(category_name=category)




'''
urls.py
'''
from .views import CategoryListView


urlpatterns = [
    # urlpatterns for other pages left out for better readability
    CategoryListView.as_view(), name='post-category')
]
```

The code gives me a 404 and the message that no Category matches my query.

Comment: The `urlpatterns` seem incomplete?

Comment: categorie -> category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`get_queryset`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) function should return something like:

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):

    # ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Furthermore in your url, you will need to use a pattern with a `pk` parameter, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<int:pk>', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='post-category')
]
```

That being said, if you want to display information about the category, it might make more sense to make it a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), and then query the relation in reverse, like:

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category'
    template_name = 'posts/post_category.html'
```

and in the template, you can render data with:

```
Category name: {{ category.name }}
{% for post in category.post_set.all %}
    post: {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would this mean that when trying to navigate to the site I'd have to go to [first_part_of_url]/category/category_id instead of [first_part_of_url]/category/category_name?

Comment: @codecodecode: your `return reverse('post-category', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})` suggests that you navigate to `rooturl/category/123`, so with `123` the `pk` of the category. You can use a slug instead.

Comment: I see, thanks again for your help – it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but how dow I reverse the order of it to always show the latest post first?

```
Category name: {{ category.name }}
{% for post in category.post_set.all %}
    post: {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sorry, just figured it out myself, in models
class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
works fine.

Comment: this seems to be a new question?